# Waring's prime number conjecture

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, primes

This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_prime_number_conjecture):

> In mathematics, Waring's prime number conjecture is a conjecture in number theory, closely related to Vinogradov's theorem. The conjecture is named after the English mathematician Edward Waring and states that every odd integer exceeding 3 is either a prime number or the sum of three prime numbers. The conjecture is known to follow from the generalized Riemann hypothesis.

My code:

```
 def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

def prime_number(maximum):
  number_list=(i for i in range(1,maximum+1))
  divisor=1
  divisor_list=[]
  prime_number_list=[]
  for e in number_list:
    while divisor<=e:
      if e%divisor==0:
        divisor_list.append(divisor_list)
        divisor+=1
      else:
        divisor+=1
    if len(divisor_list)==2:
      prime_number_list.append(e)
      prime_number_list.append(e)
      prime_number_list.append(e)
      prime_number_list.append(e)
      divisor=1
      divisor_list=[]
    else:
      divisor=1
      divisor_list=[]
  return prime_number_list


def div_by_two(num):
  if num%2==0:
    return False
  else:
    return True

def Waring_Number(maximum):
  input_list=range(5,maximum+1)
  combination_of_prime_number=combinations(prime_number(maximum),3)
  prime_number_list=prime_number(maximum)
  odd_number=[i for i in input_list if div_by_two(i)]
  for e in odd_number:
    if e in prime_number_list:
      print ("{} is a prime number.".format(e))
    else:
        for combination in combination_of_prime_number:
          if sum(combination)==e:
            print ("{}+{}+{}={}".format(combination[0],combination[1],combination[2],e))
            break
```

Few Notes:

- I just copied and pasted the combination function from `itertools` documentation, I do not know how the function actually works, only how it works.
- `prime_number_list.append(e)` was repeated four times because the combinations had to include prime numbers being repeated three times too. (For example, (3,3,3) has to be created for Waring Number to work) I know this takes up time.
- I am a beginner. I have only been doing Python for few months for hobby and only know the basics

Any and all feedback is welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason you copy/pasted `combinations` instead of just importing it?

Comment: Because I thought itertool only worked in Python 2 and I was working on Python 3.

Comment: Nah. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations. They just took some stuff out that was made redundant due to other update, I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming.** Mostly good. You're making the effort to be descriptive with it, which is awesome. I would change `odd_number` to `odd_numbers` since it's a list. Also, `prime_number` really tells me nothing about what the function is actually doing. Not going to suggest an alternative name, because I'll have more to say about this function later. `Warring_Number` violates PEP 8. (`warring_number` instead.)

**More, descriptive functions.** This can make it easier to get a high-level understanding of what's going on when you're reading it. For example, at the start of `warring_number`, you could do `odd_numbers = get_odd_numbers_in_interval(5, maximum)`. More importantly though, in your `prime_number` function, you can just do:

```
for e in number_list:
    if is_prime(e):
        #etc.
```

This not only makes it more clear what you're doing. You're also making it so that when you want to speed up checking if a number is prime, you don't have to worry about how that logic will affect anything else. It's all right in one place.

Speaking of...

**Avoid brute force.** If you finding yourself iterating over every single possibility, it's usually worth it to see if there's a clever way to speed things up. Checking if a number is prime has been researched a lot, so I would just go to Wikipedia or StackOverflow and use an algorithm that I'm not smart enough to come up with myself. For checking if a number is a sum of three primes, let's think about it.

Right now, your check for, say, 13 looks something like this:

```
2 + 2 + 2 = 6
2 + 2 + 3 = 7
2 + 2 + 5 = 9
2 + 2 + 7 = 11
2 + 2 + 11 = 15
etc.
```

Let's do it manually, and apply a bit of thought.

```
for i in list_of_primes:
    for j in list_of_primes:
```

At this point, there is a unique number `x` such that `i + j + x = e`. So let's just check that and move on

```
        if is_prime(e - (i + j)):
```

**More on `prime_numbers`:** I really don't like that it returns 4 values of each prime. It's not an obvious thing to do, and I would prefer to have the calling code manipulate the return value so it looks like it needs to. In any case, you already have a use for the function where you don't want duplicates of every prime. Additionally, it is a rather expensive function, and you call it twice. Instead, you could do:

```
prime_number_list = prime_number(maximum)
combination_of_prime_number = combinations(prime_number_list, 3)
```

**Style comments:** Spaces around operators, please. `if e % divisor == 0` is much easier to read than `if e%divisor==0`.

Instead of

```
if boolean:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

You can just do:

```
return not boolean
```

Actually, I believe this is a bug in `div_by_two`. It should just be

```
def div_by_two(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Which would simplify to

```
def div_by_two(n):
    return n % 2 == 0
```

Comment: The code looks much cleaner and runs much faster, thanks for the advice.